# Python gettext Genitiv 's

Tags: python, gettext

I want to translate a text into German but I have trouble with the genitive 's. In German, we don't have an inverted comma after the genitive ("John's car" -> "Johns Auto" (Auto is German for car)) except the word ends with an s ("James's car" -> "James' Auto").
So, if I have the following:

```
_("%(name)'s car is nice") % name
```

The results for "John" and "James" are:

```
John's car is nice      -> Correct
Johns Auto ist schön    -> Correct (ist means is and schön means nice or beautiful).
James's car is nice     -> Correct
Jamess Auto is schön    -> Wrong it has to be James'
```

Since I'm the developer of the program, I can also update the source code and add new functions.

Comment: I don't think that "James's" is correct.

Comment: So you basically want to test whether the last letter is `s`? This can be done with `mystring[-1]=="s"`.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini it is correct. http://www.proz.com/kudoz/English/linguistics/992067-james_car_or_jamess_car_british_english.html (And it also applies to American English).

Comment: If this is really about translating, bear in mind that in German only masculina and neutra (and not all of those) from the genetive singluar with "-s". "My mother's car" -> "Meiner Mutter Auto" or more commonly "Das Auto meiner Mutter". No "-s" ending at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function to make the genitiv:

```
def genitiv(name):
    if name[-1]=='s':
       return _(u"%s'" % name)
    else:
       return _(u"%s's" % name)
```

Comment: It will not work for the English text. If the language is set in English, it will be "James' car is nice" which is not wrong but  Chicago Manual of Style recommends not to use it. And I don't want to add this function every time I use a genitive.

Comment: you can use the same format string in english and use a contextual marker to identify it for the two different usages. Then in the German translation you can differentiate it.